# Dynamic grouping of data|| SQL query needed

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Year        Salary
2014        5000
2015        6500
2016        6800
2017        6900
2018        7000
2019        8000
```

I want to group data dynamically. Suppose if i want group of 2 then data should be grouped in 3 groups of 2 years each
Resultset as :

```
Year          Salary
2014-2015     11500
2016-2017     13300
2018-2019     15000
```

If i want group of 3 then,

```
Year.            Salary
2014-2016        18300
2017-2019        21900
```

No hardcoding

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using window functions and aggregation.  Assuming you want *n* years in each group:

```
select min(year), max(year), sum(salary)
from (select t.*, min(year) over () as min_year
      from t
     ) t
group by floor((year - min_year) / @n)
order by min(year);
```

Comment: Brillant. One may refer : [solution](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=52bb1261ba2a614ef6c6aa0785edaf59)

Answer (score 0):

For example you can create a few variables that will help you in creating groups within the table i.e. 2014-2015 etc. Adjusting `@RowsToGroup` you can group as many rows as you want. `@remainder` helps to find next groups within `Year`. In the `CTE` I used `sum as a window function` plus `case` to create a column to `group by`.

```
create table #years (Year int,        Salary int )
insert into #years values (2014        ,5000)
insert into #years values (2015        ,6500)
insert into #years values (2016        ,6800)
insert into #years values (2017        ,6900)
insert into #years values (2018        ,7000)
insert into #years values (2019        ,8000)

declare @minYear int = (select min(Year) from #years);
declare @RowsToGroup int = 2;
declare @remainder decimal(12,6) = (select @minYear % @RowsToGroup) ;

with YearsToGroup as (
select 
     *
    ,sum(case when Year % @RowsToGroup = @remainder then 1 else 0 end) over (order by Year asc) as grouping
from #years
)
select 
    cast(min(Year) as varchar(10)) + '-' + cast(max(Year) as varchar(10)) as years
    ,sum(salary) as salary
from YearsToGroup
group by grouping
```

Results for @RowsToGroup = 2:

```
years       salary
2014-2015   11500
2016-2017   13700
2018-2019   15000
```

Results for @RowsToGroup = 3:

```
years       salary
2014-2016   18300
2017-2019   21900
```

Comment: I am confused how remainder is helpful.  Please add output of select * from YearsToGroup if it's not too much trouble? For instance,  if you group years by their remainder,  don't you end up grouping all odd years together?

Comment: This remainder is crucial here 'case when Year % RowsToGroup = remainder then 1 else 0 end'. It helps to find boundaries between groups. When it finds the same remainder it adds +1, so a new group is created.

Comment: still confused but maybe the root cause is answer to both questions:  A) how you can sum without group by in WITH statement and B)in final query how does "grouping" group consecutive years together when consecutive years must have a different remainder?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1** use division by your number of years and round down to devise nested function calls that return the YearGroup desired.  This could get messy but it's possible

**Option 2** - the most flexible across any sql platform would be to add a YearGroup table (or view) with one column per desired  group

```
Year | GroupOne  | GroupTwo | GroupThree
-----+-----------+----------+-----------
2019 | 2019.1    | 2018.2   | 2019.3
2018 | 2018.1    | 2018.2   | 2016.3
2017 | 2017.1    | 2016.2   | 2016.3
2016 | 2016.1    | 2016.2   | 2016.3
2015 | 2015.1    | 2014.2   | 2015.3
...
```

The decimals are optional but good to let people know number of years in group though I guess true third normal form would be one table per years grouped

Option 2 has the added benefit that anyone can select from the YearGroup table(s) to see the mapping first hand

You could also add groups that have different anchor years like group two years with odd as first year(merge 2017 and 2018) vs even as first year (merge 2018 with 2019)